# Calendar/Date timezone Conversion issue

Tags: java, database

I will get a Date like `Sat May 31 16:38:17 GMT 2014`. In DB also column has the same value. But when I will  search for date like `Sat May 31 16:30:00 GMT 2014` it wont search. But If I give less than `5:30 hours` like `Sat May 31 11:00:00 GMT 2014` . It works fine.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT-0:00" ));
cal.setTimeInMillis(inputDate.getTime());
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
inputDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: What timezone is the database using?

Comment: When I executed "select dbtimezone from dual" it gave "+00:00"

Comment: Ok. What exactly are you doing. Inserting into database? Selecting from DB? And how (as in 'code example')?

Comment: I am selecting from DB based to date input given by user. Above code snippet code shows how I am trying to convert input date to calendar object and set timezone to GMT 0:00. But it's not converting.

Comment: I guess your system runs in the IST time zone?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying implementation of `Date` and `Calendar` both use the same system: a `long` representing milliseconds since 1st of January 1970, 0:00:00 GMT.
See [Here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Date.java.html) for `Date` (lines 136 & 168) and [HERE](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Calendar.java.html) for `Calendar` (line 778)

So this gets us to this:

```
   cal.setTimeInMillis(inputDate.getTime());
   // this gets the long from the Date and puts it into the Calendar
   // nothing is changed, you only get added functionality
   // even if you change the Timezone this only affects how it is displayed

   cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
   // the long is modified by setting the that represents only milliseconds to zero

   inputDate = cal.getTime();
   //the long is stored in a Date and returned
```

You get back a minimally altered `Date` object. Without the second instruction there would be no change at all.

This explains why nothing is converted, but not why the select doesn't work.

From the info you gave it seems there is a mismatch in the timezones of trinity of the DB, the JVM and your system.

Something in the line of this: your system is set to IST and your JVM somehow interprets your system time as GMT. To check this you could run `System.out.println(new Date())`. If it writes out the timezone as GTM but the numbers are the same as your systems clock (IST) then that is your problem.

You could also check:

- do the time-stamps of an insert statement match with what arrives in the database
- do the time-stamps of a database entry match the one you receive after a select